# Como deixar um CRUD persistente?

Tags: java

Fiz um CRUD simples, e queria deixar os dados dele salvo, para quando abrir o Netbeans está todas as informações salvas.

Comment: Você pode explicar melhor? Está difícil entender só com o que você já disse.

Answer (score 4):

Você precisará de um banco de dados para salvar as informações. Se for uma aplicação robusta, eu recomendo o [postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org.br/) com a administração do [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) junto com o [pgModeler](http://www.pgmodeler.com.br/) para fazer os relacionamentos visualmente. Agora se você preferir pode utilizar uma base de dados muito veloz, recomendo o MySQL utilizando o Workbench.

Aconselho a utilizar como API a JPA, que é uma convenção de como você deve implementar seus *providers*. Neste caso eu recomendo o Hibernate.

Não tenha pressa para aprender, aprenda os conceitos de forma sólida. Eu atualmente estou estudando tudo isso também.

Comment: Não é estritamente necessário usar um banco de dados. As informações podem ser persistidas em um arquivo no filesystem, por exemplo.